# Ransford Potential Theory in the Complex Plane execise 1.3.5

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I am denoting as $D(z,r)$ the disk in the complex plane, centered at $z$ with radius $r$. Let $h$ be a function harmonic on a neighbourhood of $\overline{D(0,\rho)}$ and for $0\leq r\leq \rho$ define
$$M_h(r)\doteqdot \sup_{|z|=r}h(z)$$
The question is to prove that

$$M_h(r)\leq \frac{2r}{\rho+r}M_h(\rho)+\frac{\rho-r}{\rho+r}h(0)\qquad(0\leq r\leq \rho).$$

I could not do much to progress this problem. As I can say, since $h$ is not necessarily positive, tools like Harnack Inequality cannot be used here. So one may only has its hope for using the Poisson-Integral Formula, which states that for $0\leq r\leq \rho$,

$$h(re^{it})=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\rho^2-r^2}{\rho^2-2\rho r\cos(\theta-t)+r^2}h(\rho e^{i\theta})d\theta\qquad (0\leq t\leq 2\pi).$$

Even so, I cannot see what estimations I may use so that even the first term in the right hand side in the above inequality can be obtained. In particular, I cannot see how such denominator appears.

I am thanking beforehand anyone who wishes to help me figure out this exercise.

Best regards.

Comment: Why not just let $g:=f-\inf_{C_r} f$ to guarantee nonnegative harmonic and proceed the same way?

Comment: It is not clear to me why such $g$ is harmonic. Even so accepting this as fact, I could not conclude to the above answer. Is it possible to elaborate more on this?

Comment: Note $g$ is just $f$ plus a constant, so is nonnegative harmonic.

Comment: I have then trouble to understand how you define $g$. If for $z: |z|=r$, $g(z)\doteqdot f(z)-\inf_{C_r}f(z)$, then such function is the sum of harmonic and a radial one. One may use further tools to aqcuire that the second can be a subharmonic in general function. If this is not what you write, can you explain further how you define $g$?

Comment: $f$ has a minimum on the circle $C_r=\{re^{it}\mid t\in\mathbb{R}\}$ and we are just shifting $f$ by this constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish to personally thank user10354138 for claryfying this question, so that we have this answer.

Since $h$ is harmonic on a neighbourhood of $\overline{D(0,\rho)}$, we have that
$$M_\rho (h)=M<+\infty.$$
In particular, the function
$$M-h\text{ is harmonic in a neighbourhood of }\overline{D(0,\rho)}\,.$$
It is also positive on the disk $D(0,\rho)$. Hence, it justfies the use of Harnack's Inequality and so
$$(M_\rho-h)(re^{it})\geq \frac{\rho-r}{\rho+r}(M_\rho-h)(0)\qquad(0\leq r<\rho)\,.$$
After some computations, we conclude that
$$h(re^{it})\leq \frac{2r}{\rho+r}M_\rho+\frac{\rho-r}{\rho+r}h(0)$$
Taking now the supremum over all $t\in[0,2\pi]$, we reach to a conclusion. That is,
$$M_r(h)\leq \frac{2r}{\rho+r}M_\rho+\frac{\rho-r}{\rho+r}h(0)\,.$$
The case $r=\rho$ is trivialy justified.